Derivative of the complex power function (by definition)
Recall that it is defined by $f(z)=z^c=e^{clog (z)}$, I think we could use the following property
$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+ x^{n-3}y^2+ \cdots + y^{n-1})$$
whereby
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z \to z_{0}} \frac{f(z)-f(z_{0})}{z-z_{0}}&= \lim_{z \to z_{0}} \frac{z^c-z_{0}^c}{z-z_{0}} \\
&=\lim_{z \to z_{0}} \frac{(z-z_0)(z^{c-1}+z^{c-2}z_0+\cdots + z_{0}^{c-1})}{z-z_{0}} \\
&=\lim_{z \to z_{0}} z^{c-1}+z^{c-2}z_0+\cdots + z_{0}^{c-1} \\
&= z_0^{c-1}+z_0^{c-2}z_0+\cdots + z_{0}^{c-1} \\
&=c z_0^{c-1}
\end{align*}
this works when $c$ is a natural value greater than $1$, but what about the remaining cases? is there any way to deal with them? any help would be appreciated!

If you are allowed to use the chain rule, one gets (at least in the real case):
\begin{align*}
f(x) := x^{\alpha} = \exp\left(\alpha\ln(x)\right) \Rightarrow f'(x) = \frac{\alpha\exp\left(\alpha\ln(x)\right)}{x} = \alpha x^{\alpha - 1}
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!
